# VS 2013 Git integration - customize compare with unmodified option?

Tags: vb.net, git, visual-studio, integration, visual-studio-2013

I am researching Git for VS 2013, and it seems pretty solid so far. However, it seems to be lacking customization options.

**First question:** With TFS and subversion (AnkhSVN) I am able to configure my own custom compare and merge tools (I am using CodeCompare, no affiliation, just a preference). Example for TFS:

[image]

There are no similar options with Git, even thought it's a *Microsoft* Git Provider. Am I missing a plugin?

[image]

**Second question:** I also could not find an option to do "Compare" with a double click. It is very unproductive to right-click and go to "Compare with unmodified" every time.

[image]

VS 2013 has a nice option to view only modified files, so I was going to use that + key or mouse combination (I've tried Shift-dblClick - no luck). Did anyone manage to discover such combination?

[image]

Comment: if you have found any solution could you please share.

Comment: @Morbia: Did not find a solution yet, probably because I don't work with Git on a regular basis. Thank you for posting your ideas below. I will accept it as an answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick at [How to use an external diff tool for Git in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036294/how-to-use-external-diff-tool-for-git-in-visual-studio-2013?rq=1) has helped me to fix this issue.

```
    [diff]
    guitool = winmerge
        tool = winmerge

    [difftool "winmerge"]
        path = C:/Tools/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe
        cmd = C:/Tools/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```